# Help with ISO 14230 K-Line initialisation

Tags: stm32, automotive, firmware, obd

I have an OBD-II scanner hardware built using STM32 and it is working fine with most vehicles.But I'm facing difficulty with ISO 14320 K-Line fast.

Even though the firmware **works fine when tested with an emulator** it constantly **fails** when it is scanning an **actual KWP-Fast car**.

A brief of KWP-Fast: We sent a wake-up pulse followed by a sequence of 5 bytes to initialize the communication between the scanner and the car's ECU. And in return to this, we must receive 7 bytes along with a reflection of the 5 bytes we sent. But I'm only receiving these 5 bytes and nothing else. This is the scenario for the car environment, but when tested with an emulator I receive the needed 7 bytes too.

Does anyone have experience with ISO 14320 K-Line protocol who can help me with their past experience? I'm having a "Timeout" waiting for those 7 bytes.

*Are there specific ECU address that a tested/scanner must be communicating with?

*Since it worked with an OBD emulator the timing must be right, or is it at the timing my firmware is screwing up?

*I refer to the ISO documentation and so the logic must be right, and so I assume I'm trying to communicate with a wrong or non-existing ECU and so does not receive any response. (same as point 1)

*Do we need a wake-up pulse when scanning a car? As wouldn't that already be done by the internal ECUs.

Comment: You should attach a scope and observe what is actually happening on the wire

Comment: @PlasmaHH Thank you, I don't own a scope so using a LabJack U3. Will update this thread once I have some lead.